# .htaccess mvc url rewrite in subfolder and subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need your help to manage my app url with seo friendly way, so i need to rewrite some urls, let's do some examples:

- current url types : http://sub.app.com/index.php?router=page&param1=A&param2=B
- desired seo url   : http://sub.app.com/page/A/B  [ other parameters /C/D/E/... ]

Sorry but i really new with .htaccess and preg_match.
I beg on you, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?router=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?router=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?router=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?router=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5&param5=$6 [L]
# etc...
```

In my opinion it is not possible to do it automatically for a variable number of elements.
But it is not too complicated to add more lines if necessary.